# Deep Learning syntax error in skimage.morphology

Tags: python, deep-learning, feature-extraction, scikit-image

i have a piece of python code that is intended to extract letters and label each region that contains an image.

edit: I'm using google colab

I get the following error:

```
 print label_image.max()
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i've tried back tracking versions of python etc but have not found a solution. Any help is apprietiated thanks.
full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from scipy.misc import imread,imresize
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.morphology import label
from skimage.measure import regionprops


image = imageio.imread('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/985792111713947648/7YD1ZYpe_400x400.jpg')



#apply threshold in order to make the image binary
bw = image < 120

# remove artifacts connected to image border
cleared = bw.copy()
clear_border(cleared)

# label image regions
label_image = label(cleared,neighbors=8)
borders = np.logical_xor(bw, cleared)
label_image[borders] = -1

print label_image.max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(6, 6))
ax.imshow(bw, cmap='jet')
```

Comment: `print(label_image.max())`

Comment: In python 2, `print` was a keyword and `print label_image.max()` was correct. In python 3, `print` is just a regular function, so `print(label_image.max())`

Comment: Which begs the question, which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using google colab so I'm guessing it should be the latest version?

Comment: I tried jordam's solution which provides a new error scipy.misc.                 
  `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-730adddc452e> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 image = imageio.imread('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/985792111713947648/7YD1ZYpe_400x400.jpg')
      3 
      4 
      5 

NameError: name 'imageio' is not defined`

Comment: the newest versions of scipy ask for imageio.imread according to the docs. how is this an error?